# How to Use Java 8 settings to build project in eclipse 4.18(2020-12)

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, jaxb, java-11

*Due to some project requirements I "have" to use eclipse 4.18 (2020-12) which uses Java 11 by default and is mandatory to start.

But my entire project is/was written in Java 1.7 earlier. Now , in my mac i have both java 1.8 and 11 installed also my eclipse settings are such shown below.
I have made sure removed all java 11 references in my eclipse and made the project and workspace configure to take the 1.8 jdk and run at 1.7 compiler level.*
*but when i run ,project -->clean-->build, i run into the JaxB missing in java 11 ( in java 11 JAXB was removed and my project uses jaxB extensively) This is known.*

**So i am wondering what am i missing that my projects are still building my project with java 11 and not java 1.7 (using jdk 1.8 configured).
Please help.. stuck on this since some days.**

[machome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tf18f.png)

[Eclipse Compiler setting-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c2on.png)

[Eclipse Setting Execution Envs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jra1l.png)

[Eclipse installed JRE's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHSIP.png)

[Eclipse Project specific setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yzwe.png)

[Java 11 JaxB error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6YIW.png)

Comment: It's not recommended to use images unless strictly necessary. To answer your question someone will have to open all links. Try to [improve your question please.](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What is "Design Studio Platform Builder", and why is it not compatible with running Eclipse using Java 11?

Comment: What do you have configured for JavaSE-1.7 in "Installed JREs > Execution Environments"?

Comment: @nitind its actually a oracle design studio plug in which we use to configure oracle products.. its built by them and for now they dont have java 11 support

Comment: @greg-449 in installed JRE's i have "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home/bin" and in Execution environments --> JavaSE-1.7 -->Compatible Jres -->Java Se 8 [1.8.0_251] selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Eclipse itself is being run with Java 11, and you have a plug-in installed that has not been properly update to work under Java 11, as it appears, you will need an updated version of that plug-in. Update to the latest "oracle design studio", and if you still see this problem, contact Oracle support.

Comment: Oh this makes sense. Its the Oracle DS plug-in that might be using the JVM of the eclipse and hence this error is arising. Got It. . ill mark this as an answer.. Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

The latest Eclipse may require Java 11 to run, but it's simple to set up Eclipse projects that use older Java versions.  Don't mess with the Java version it uses to start up, as long as that is a proper Java 11 version.

As one commenter mentions, you'll have to have a particular Java distribution configured in "Installed JREs->Execution Environments", and then you'll have to have the project configured to use that Java version symbol, like "JavaSE-1.7".

Comment: Hello @david ,  i have configured Execution Environments -->JavaSe 1.7 and the Compatible Jres  checkbok selected for Java Se 8 [1.8.0_251]. 
The Setup looks ok , but its still building my project with java 11, hence i am stuck .

Comment: I suggest you show all of your configuration settings.